# text to appear in a cell upon input of yes in a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

Hi I need a fix to this please help with a formula.

Please refer above picture.

on input of yes in I 8709 i want the word "printed" in J8709

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A simple IF

```
=IF(I8709 = "yes","Printed","")
```